# chmod is not working

Tags: permissions, chmod, media

I am unable to change the privileges of the directory or file which is not in desktop using chmod. while it is working properly for the directory and folders of desktop.
am using the command

```
chmod 000 /media/drivename/dirname
```

what should I do??

Comment: what is your aim?

Answer (score 2):

[You can't do chmod on a drive:](https://askubuntu.com/a/11843/186134)

> The mode is determined by the partition's mount options (you cannot change it via chmod).

Comment: You *can* chmod 000 a file if you own it.

Comment: @Oli edited that in

Comment: Ok I got you @Tim but the command sudo chmod 000 /media/drivename/dirname is also not working..even when I am on shell as a root..

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look first:
1. What is partition type for drivename,
as this under directory media it should be removeable media
2. Check if partition is writeable
$ mount |grep drivename
it should show (rw,..something)

if not, please remount with rw options, or take require installation to have writeable

hope this help